# What is the purpose for no gpgcheck in the pgdg-redhat-all.repo?

Tags: postgresql, redhat

A repository installed from the official [PostgreSQL site](https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64) (`/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm`) has gpgcheck disabled for PostgreSQL 17 Downloads. See below.

```
[pgdg17-updates-testing]
name=PostgreSQL 17 for RHEL / Rocky $releasever - $basearch - Updates testing
baseurl=https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/testing/17/redhat/rhel-$releasever-$basearch
enabled=0
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG
repo_gpgcheck = 1

[pgdg17-source-updates-testing]
name=PostgreSQL 17 for RHEL / Rocky $releasever - $basearch - Source updates testing
baseurl=https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/srpms/testing/17/redhat/rhel-$releasever-$basearch
enabled=0
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG
repo_gpgcheck = 1
```

Why is that?

Edit: After contacting PostgreSQL support they confirmed that it is for faster rpm builds. This issue will be corrected later.

Comment: PostgreSQL 17 is under development and its not currently ready for production. Maybe it's for faster rpm builds.

Comment: You should ask on the yum packagers list. Only Devrim can tell for certain.

Comment: @SahapAsci You are indeed correct. PostgreSQL support confirmed this. Will be editing my post.

Comment: You should post what you edited into your question, as an answer, because that's what it is.